# error message "unused argument" with R software

Tags: error-handling

I have used this script several times and its worked, but this time when I run the same script and got error messages.
anyone can help me?

thanks anyway

```
library(replicateBE)
path.in  <- "C:/Users/noviy/OneDrive/Documents/OMFL/test R"
path.out <- path.in
method.A(path.in=path.in, path.out=path.out, file="Lans1",
         set="AUCt", ext="xlsx", header=1, ola=TRUE)
method.A(path.in=path.in, path.out=path.out, file="Lans1",
    set="Cmax", ext="xlsx", header=1)
method.A(path.in=path.in, path.out=path.out, file="Lans1",
    set="AUCinf", ext="xlsx", header=1)
ABE(path.in=path.in, path.out=path.out, file="Lans1",
    set="AUCt", ext="xlsx", header=1)
ABE(path.in=path.in, path.out=path.out, file="Lans1",
    set="Cmax", ext="xlsx", header=1)
ABE(path.in=path.in, path.out=path.out, file="Lans1",
    set="AUCinf", ext="xlsx", header=1)

Error in method.A(path.in = path.in, path.out = path.out, file = "Lans1",  : unused argument (header = 1)

Error in method.A(path.in = path.in, path.out = path.out, file = "Lans1",  : unused argument (header = 1)

Error in method.A(path.in = path.in, path.out = path.out, file = "Lans1",  : unused argument (header = 1)

Error in ABE(path.in = path.in, path.out = path.out, file = "Lans1", set = "AUCt",  : unused argument (header = 1)

Error in ABE(path.in = path.in, path.out = path.out, file = "Lans1", set = "Cmax",  : unused argument (header = 1)

Error in ABE(path.in = path.in, path.out = path.out, file = "Lans1", set = "AUCinf",  : unused argument (header = 1)
```